# SCSS - Why is rule `&-classA.&-classB` not allowed?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm getting into SCSS trying to organise my css code and I came about this problem which peeked my interested as to why it's throwing a error?

here some example code:

```
<div class='bot'>
    <div class='bot-active bot-awake'>
        //...
    </div>
</div>
```

And my SCSS looks like:

```
.bot {
    &-active {....}
    &-awake {....}

    // this will not work.
    &-active.&-awake {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not using sass, but when in `&` is `.bot`, can work `&-active&-awake` without a dot between? I can't to test it now.

Comment: @panther unforunalty on, just tested it.

Comment: "this will not work." Does it give a compile error?

Comment: `Invalid CSS after \"-active\": expected \"{\", was \"&-active\"\n\n\"&-awake\" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [interpolation `#{}`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____)

So

```
.bot {
    &-active {....}
    &-awake {....}

    // this will work.
    &-active#{&}-awake {
        ...
    }
}
```

will result in

```
.bot-active {
  ...
}
.bot-awake {
  ...
}
.bot-active.bot-awake {
  ...
}
```

Demo at https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/4b8eb66140de9da983650b41a6df66ae

Comment: Thanks for that was not aware of interpolation. However its strange why mine above don't work.

Comment: @Kivylius it is just not supported.